# Determining end of dynamic array in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have a user-defined struct call MyStruct and allocate a 2D dynamic array:

```
MyStruct** arr = (MyStruct**) malloc(sizeof(myStruct*)*size);
```

I want to process the array in a function:

```
void compute(MyStruct** lst)
{
    int index = 0;
    while(lst[index] != NULL)
    {  
        //do something
        index++;
    }
}
```

I called `compute(arr)` and it works fine. But valgrind complains that there is an invalid read of size `sizeof(MyStruct)` at line `while(...)`. I understand that at this point index is out of bound by 1 element. An easy fix is to pass `size` to the function and check if `index < size` through the loop.

Out of curiosity, is there anyway I can still traverse through the array without indexing that extra element AND not passing `size` to the function?

Comment: How do you initialize your array?

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard way, no.

That said, there may be some nonstandard ways you can get the allocated size of a `malloc`ed piece of memory. For example, my machine has a [`size_t malloc_size(const void *);`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/malloc_size.3.html) function in `<malloc/malloc.h>`; glibc has a `malloc_usable_size` function with a similar signature; and Microsoft’s libc implementation has an [`_msize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2s077bc.aspx) function, also with a similar signature.

These cannot simply be dropped in, though; besides the obvious portability concerns, these return the actual amount of memory allocated for you, *which might be slightly more than you requested*. That might be okay for some applications, but perhaps not for iterating through your array.

You probably ought to just pass the size as a second parameter. Boring, I know.

Comment: Instead of passing size, you could also consider null terminating the list since its an array of pointers =)